# Spark worker not able connect to the Master

Tags: apache-spark, archlinux

I have set up SSH and I'm able to ping between the master and the workers. But when I run `start-all.sh`, I get the following exception thrown:

```
SparkExeption: Invalid master URL: spark://masterurl
```

I've already added the `SPARK_MASTER_IP` in the worker's `spark-env.sh`.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Try different port. Check the master log

Comment: This comes when you have made changes in spark-defaults file. If you have not then add properties spark.master                     spark://<master>:<port> at both master and worker nodes.

Comment: @Nikk can you point out which file I should add the property you mentioned at both the master and worker nodes?

Comment: the filename is spark-defaults which will be at config folder add properties as    
                                       spark.master            spark://<masternode>:<port>    #eg   spark://master:7077